# sd card keeps getting unmounted when htc sensation is being charged

Tags: charging, usb-connection-mode, external-sd, htc-sensation

i have an htc sensation and it keeps saying that the sd card has been removed when its still in the phone. it will also say that the sd card has unmounted when it is charging  What is going on?

Comment: Are you charging it through the computer? Or through a power outlet?

Comment: Does this happen *only* when on charging or at random? Please edit the question with more details also mention Android version / ROM that you are running so that folks will be able to help you better.

Comment: When you first plug into a computer you are often given a choice about how to connect to the computer. Charge only, mount as storage, etc.. You then also often have a choice of making your choice the default from then on. So the behavior you describe can occur when you have chose to mount the phone as storage for the computer by default whenever it is plugged in. You can change these settings in the phone settings.